# How to make an input and a slider together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, three.js

I am experimenting with `CSS` 3D transforms and I am trying to make sliders to handle the transforms. I came up with the [editor of Three.js](http://threejs.org/editor/) and I liked the idea of how it handles the position, rotation and scale of each object. It's an input and a slider in the same time or I just assume.

I haven't figured out how this works even after checking the source code and I'd like to give me a code snippet achieving the same functionality. Concretely, to have an input value and by just sliding the value right/left the object moves or by giving manually a value.

Note: I am not interested in the functionality of transforms only how such an input-slider can be done.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a (very) simple jQuery plugin that emulates what you're after (for integers). I'll leave extending it to handle Floats as an exercise for you.

JSFiddle with added CSS for cursors at http://jsfiddle.net/yRmHS/3/

```
jQuery.fn.slidingInput = function (opts) {

    var defaults = {
        step: 1,        // Increment value
        min: 0,         // Minimum value
        max: 100,       // Maximum value
        tolerance: 2    // Mouse movement allowed within a simple click
    };

    return this.each(function () {
        var $el = $(this),
            options = $.extend({}, defaults, opts, this),
            distance = 0,
            initialValue = 0;

        function mouseDown () {
            distance = 0;
            initialValue = parseInt($el.val(), 10);

            $(document).on('mousemove', mouseMove).on('mouseup', mouseUp);

            return false;
        }

        function mouseMove (e) {
            var currentValue = parseInt($el.val(), 10),
                event = e.originalEvent,
                movementX = event.movementX || event.webkitMovementX || event.mozMovementX || 0,
                movementY = event.movementY || event.webkitMovementY || event.mozMovementY || 0;

            distance += (movementX - movementY) * options.step;

            $el.val(Math.min(options.max, Math.max(initialValue + distance, options.min)));
        }

        function mouseUp () {
            $(document).off('mousemove mouseup');

            if (Math.abs(distance) < options.tolerance) {
                $el.focus();
            }
        }

        $el.on('mousedown', mouseDown);
    });
};

// How to use it
$(function () {
    // Initialise plugin
    // HTML sample: <input type="number" class="slidable" step="2" value="50" min="0" max="100" />
    $('.slidable').slidingInput();

    // Accepts options object that override defaults, but step/min/max on input override options
    /*
        $('.slidable').slidingInput({
            step: 1,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            tolerance: 2
        });
    */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `input`s are in a `div` and are styled to look like lables: no border, no background. There is a style on the `input`s that changes the cursor into a slider-cursor (`cursor:col-resize`).

There is probably an `onmousedown/onmouseup` listener on the `input`s and then an `onmousemove` to get the mouse position while the mouse is down. I've found that putting one global `onmousemove` handler on the `body` works best. If you put the `onmousemove` event on a small element you wont get the events when the mouse is no longer over the element. As you can see in the three.js editor you can mousedown and then move the mouse anywhere on the page.

You probably need to use `event.preventDefault()` to make sure the `onmousedown` doesn't trigger a focus on the input element.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but most of them are easy to figure out from developer tools. The difficult part for me is to toggle the slider and the input with javascript. I googled something similar but I can't find any working example.

Comment: If this _"easy to figure out"_ then why don't you produce your own code sample? I've outlined what the script could look like, all you need to do is write the code.

Comment: @giokokos Since you're familiar with developer tools, why don't you look at how the Three.js editor implements it (it's quite re-usable). The bits of interest to you are in http://threejs.org/editor/js/UI.js UI.Number on line 605 and UI.Integer on line 768

Comment: Thanks @thefrontender. I'll take a look at it and try to make a working example and post it here as an answer.